# Android 12 accent color in Light / Dark Theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-12

I am little bit lost in colors scheme on Android 12. If a user changes color scheme, the color of the notification icon will change too (see arrow in the picture below). I found out that this color can be load via `?android:colorAccent` but If a user sets Dark Theme, color from `?android:colorAccent` is wrong.

How do I set for example `android:textColor` so that there is the same color as the notification icon color (light mode = darker icon, dark mode = lighter icon) for Light / Dark theme.

How can I get this color (user defined color)?

[image]